# "extern" keyword usage

Tags: c++, extern

I have the following code snippet:

```
 #include<iostream>

 int main()
 {
     extern int a;
     printf("a = %d", a)
 }
 int a = 10;
```

Above sample code print 10. My guess was it should print garbage value. Can someone explain this ?

Comment: Nope, globals have static duration, statics are initialized before `main` runs, therefore `a` already has it's value set to 10 by the time `printf` is called.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at your guess?

Comment: I thought a is not initialized when program come to print.

Comment: You are thinking as a one would in an interpreted language, not in a compiled language.

Comment: @Borgleader Can you add your comment to Answer so that i can upvote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global variables have static duration and statics are initialized before `main` runs. Therefore `a` already has it's value set to `10` by the time `printf` is called.

Answer (score 3):

The linker resolve `extern int a` to be the `a` declared after main at link time, before the program execute. As `Borgleader` said, `a` is a global variable so it initialized before main is called.

Comment: I didn't realise that @Borgleader is a piece of code.

Comment: It's widely accepted that Borgleader is most likely more of a tool than a code

Answer (score 1):

C++ programs are not executed linearly from top to bottom. `main` isn't magically executed as soon as its definition is seen during parsing.